Order parameter of vortex anti-vortex pair
I am working on a project and I am having trouble finding a source which actually calculates the order parameter from the Landau-Ginzburg equations for a vortex anti-vortex pair (superfluid or SC). Any sources are appreciated! Something where a differential equation with the VaV pair boundary conditions are solved would be great.
My confusion: I attached two plots below to show an ansatz for the profile of the order parameter, adapted from a single vortex solution. This seems reasonable until I look at the sum of the winding numbers, shown below. Due to the jump in phase along the line joining the vortices, I would think the order parameter would need to go to zero along this line for it to be well defined.
I know the energy depends on the separation of the vortices, and comes from the phase field. It seems that from calculating the energy of the pair (a standard calculation I have no trouble finding) we are summing up the energy cost due to this phase jump along this string. Any clarification on how to set this up would be nice!



There is nothing wrong with your plots here.  You think you see a $2\pi$ discontinuity in phase, but recall that $e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta + 2\pi)}$ so everything is smooth across the line.

I see. I will need to think about this more since I have a two component SC with a half vortex anti-vortex pair. A half-vortex can be established by putting a $2\pi$ phase winding in just one component. I was thinking I can treat this pair as a VaV pair in just one component, maybe I can. I am just worried about the jump in phase being $\pi$ across this string at the end of the day

Ah, half vortex.  A phase mismatch of $\pi$ is a genuine discontinuity, but you also have the orientation of the two-component order parameter reversing in direction.  Individually, orientation and phase are both discontinuous, but the two negative sign cancels when multiplied together, and the overall wavefunction is always smooth.

You are correct in stating that, topologically speaking, a half vortex in $(\eta_x, \eta_y)$ is equivalent to am ordinary vortex in one of the $\eta_{\pm} \sim \eta_x \pm i \eta_y$ component.  But $\eta_{\pm}$ will generally talk to each other, and you don't something like "a vortex in $\eta_+$ on a flat, homogeneous background of $\eta_-$".  As for actually solving the GL theory, you have to resort to numerical optimization or root finding.
